# How to get click event with javascript from an A-frame element

Tags: javascript, aframe, dom-events

UPDATE: 
You can use `onclick= function();`in the HTML.

For example:
`<a-box  onclick="myFunction()"></a-box>`

I want to get click event of cursor with javascript from an A-frame element, like a box for example, how can I do it?

Comment: Check https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/introduction/interactions-and-controllers.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the cursor component:

`box.addEventListener('click', function (evt) { // ... });`

If you want to use the mouse cursor, try https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-mouse-cursor-component

Comment: if I have more boxes than one then how can I select which one was clicked?

Comment: You know which box will be clicked from within the event handler.

Comment: Can we capture a click anywhere on the scene by using a_scene.addEventListener ?

Comment: that fiddle doesn't work in Chrome - "pointer lock on an element because the element's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-pointer-lock' permission is not set."

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom component like this;

```
<script>
AFRAME.registerComponent('clickhandler', {
        schema: {
          txt: {default:'default'}
        },        
        init: function () {
          var data = this.data;
          var el = this.el;        
          el.addEventListener('click', function () {            
           console.log(data.txt);
          });        
        }
      });
</script>

<a-image src="img1.png" clickhandler="txt:image1"></a-image>
<a-box clickhandler="txt:box1"></a-box>

<a-entity cursor="rayOrigin:mouse"></a-entity>
```

More info here
https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/core/component.html